# How can I check for a virus and malware on a USB drive using Ubuntu?

Tags: malware, virus, usb

If I plug in a USB drive in to an Ubuntu (18) machine, is it possible to get a virus?

How can I see if a (Windows, Mac or other) virus is on it?

How can I format it to remove any virus?

Comment: Is ubuntu special?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I plug in a USB drive in to an Ubuntu (18) machine, is it possible to get a virus?

It's a bit hard (execute permissions, Linux virus are rare...), but not impossible.

> How can I see if a (Windows, Mac or other) virus is on it?

You can scan the drive using an antivirus software like [ClamAV](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clamav&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all) (yes, it's not restricted to malware affecting just one platform)

> How can I format it to remove any virus?

You can use `mkfs` to format the drive. Keep in mind that this will **irreversibly destroy all data on the drive!**

NB that depending which filesystem you put on the drive, other OS may not be able to read it.